# Raspberry Pi Push Button is working itself

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, gpio, raspberry-pi3

I have to use a push button to run a bit of code. I connected a simple push button's one wire to the GROUND GPIO and the second wire to GPIO 23. And here is the code:

```
import sys
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
print "PROGRAM STARTED"
try:
    while 1:
        pay_button = GPIO.input(23)
        if pay_button == False :
            print "Payment requested."
            time.sleep(0.25)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Keyboard exit."
except:
    print "Some other error"
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

This is working good, but sometimes even if the push button is not pressed, code is working and I see "Payment requested."
It even sometimes happen when I touch to the wires. And In 60-70 cm away there is a 0.55 kW electric motor working. Seems like this GPIO is being affected static electric or this electric motor also. But I dont know how to fix this. Some resistors and capacitors?

Or if I use 3.3V or 5V GPIO pins to sense the push button instead of connecting it to GROUND?

Thanks.

Comment: I have also faced this, There will be a small voltage difference is there. So you have to use resistors.

Comment: The code is only half the system. You need to post the circuit you're using to debounce the button. See e.g. https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/robot/buttons_and_switches/

Comment: I'm not using any circuit, just connecting the cables to GPIO pins, and using internal pull up/downs.